# Both parent and child articles in archive page

Tags: custom-post-types

I used custom post types UI to create a custom post type (kennisbank)

Now within this custom post type I have both parent articles and child articles, as I made this custom post type hierarchical. I like to only display the parent articles on the archive page.

Can anyone explain me how to do this?

Comment: I've thrown up a simple answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/289374/how-to-include-the-parent-and-child-category-in-the-permalink-if-the-post-is-add/ Let me know, is this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't tried this in practice, but theoretically should be easy.

1. `post_parent` argument in query set to `0` should limit it to parent items, see [Post & Page Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).
2. Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook to correctly adjust main query, adding that argument.