# How to Include the Parent and Child Category in the Permalink if the Post is Added to Both

Tags: categories, permalinks, urls

If I add a post to a parent and child category, I know that only the parent category will be shown in the permalink. For example, if the parent category was "Clothing" and the child category was "Pants", the permalink would look like "mysite.com/clothing/post" instead of "mysite.com/clothing/pants/post".

I also know that the fix to this would be to ONLY add the post to the child category, "Pants".

My problem is that it's necessary for me to add posts to both their parent and child categories. Is there any way for me to add a post to a parent and child category AND have both the parent and child categories appear in the permalink?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few answers, scattered around this forum.  To summarise:

**Configure your Permalinks:**

1. Head to `Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks`
2. Scroll down to 'Product Permalinks' and select 'Custom Base'.
3. Enter `/%category%/` into the text field and then select 'Save'.

**Assign Product Categories:**

If your products are still not showing the Child Categories, within the URL, it could be because you are selecting both the Parent and Child Categories, for the Product to be assigned to.  Simply select the Child Category only and you should now see the Product's URL structure showing both the Parent and Child Category.